# In graphviz, can you bring two vertices closer together?

Tags: graphviz, graph-drawing

When describing a graph with graphviz, I sometimes find I want two vertices to appear closer together than the layout engine I chose places them. Is there a way to hint that I want them closer?

I'm mostly interested in the case of two connected vertices, so an answer specific to that case is fine.

---

Concrete example:

```
digraph G {
  node [shape="circle"];
  Start [shape="none" label=""];
  C [shape="doublecircle"];
  Start -> A;
  A -> B [label="0,1"];
  B -> C [label="0,1"];
  C -> D [label="0,1"];
  D -> D [label="0,1"];
}
```

[image]
I want the vertices `Start` and `A` to be closer.

Comment: Would you give an example of .gv input and resulting image to help us understand your issue

Comment: @sroush: Okay, but I have a hunch that you might not answer my general question if I do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, but you can make nearly everything else twice as big, here is a start.
(But you can't increase the size of an edge to self)

```
digraph G {
  rankdir=LR
  edge[minlen=2 fontsize=28 arrowsize=2 penwidth=2]
  node[fontsize=28 height=1 penwidth=2]
  graph[fontsize=28 penwidth=2]
  node [shape="circle"];
  Start [shape="none" label=""];
  C [shape="doublecircle"];
  Start -> A[minlen=1]; // not twice the size to get the requested effect
  A -> B [label="0,1"];
  B -> C [label="0,1"];
  C -> D [label="0,1"];
  D -> D [label="0,1"];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, this is too much of a special case; and with the self-edge, it's not clear I'm better off than I was before. But thanks for the effort...

Answer (score 0):

[this answer applies specifically to **dot**]

- there is no edge-level attribute that explicitly sets or changes edge length
- the graph-level **nodesep** attribute sets minimum distance between two nodes of same rank

so:

```
digraph G {
  nodesep=.17
  {
  rank=same
  node [shape="circle"];
  Start [shape="none" label=""];
  C [shape="doublecircle"];
  Start -> A;
  A -> B [label="0,1"];
  B -> C [label="0,1"];
  C -> D [label="0,1"];
  D -> D [label="0,1"];
  }
}
```

produces:
[image]

To increase the distance between the other nodes, you can add spaces to the labels.

I'm not wild about it either,  but this change:

```
  B -> C [label="       0,1       "]; // pad to make label (and edge) longer
```

produced this:
[image]

Comment: You mean, the edges will be at least as long as the labels? Mmm... I dunno, I don't much like this approach.